# How to show the contants in front end same as visual editor with space / linebreak?

Tags: visual-editor, html-editor, line-breaks

My visual editor looks like this:
[image: visual editor]

My text editor looks like this:
[image: text editor]

But my front end looks like this:
[image: Front end]

I know that the wordpress automatically removes linebreaks. So I installed tineMCE advace editor and checked "stop removing `<p>` and `<br>` tags" on the plugin setting.
After that line breaks were there. I saw the space. But it was adding `<p>` tag on every single line. It was so annoying. So I uninstalled the plugin.

then I added these code snippets on my **functions.php**

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

Still no luck. in front end I see a single line as my 3rd image.

Then I put this snippet on my **functions.php**

```
function clear_br($content){
        return str_replace("<br />","<br clear='none'/>", $content);
    }
    add_filter('the_content', 'clear_br');
```

Still the result is same as my images above.

My site is member based. So when a member types something on visual editor that should appear in front end as he formatted. 
We can not ask all the members to learn the HTML.

for now I am in need of two requirements.
1. Line breaks should be kept. when someone press enter the space between the next line should be appeared on front end also.
2. If I achieve that by plugin, I do not want the editor adding `<p>` tags on every single line.

How can I do that without using any plugins?
Why WP still has such a basic odd editor even the CMS is most popular?

Comment: How are you outputting your content in your theme on the front end? If using `the_content` line breaks shouldn't be removed.

Comment: @jzatt I have this code for my front end `$content = get_the_content('Read more'); print $content;` Is it incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `get_the_content()` to get your content, you need to apply filters to it to output with formatting. `apply_filters('the_content', $content);`

If you don't need to do anything with the content before outputting it, you can replace your line `$content = get_the_content('Read more); print $content;` with just `the_content();`

For reference see [`apply_filters()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters) and [`get_the_content()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content) in the codex.